# Apply VSN normalization method for Agilent microarray data in R

Tags: r

I am working with single channel Agilent microarray data for gene expression using R.After reading  the raw data, I wanted to normalize that with VSN or vsnrma method of normalization. Here is the code I applied-

```
 targets<-readTargets("Targets.txt",sep="")
 x <- read.maimages(targets$FileName, source="agilent.median", green.only=TRUE)
 y <- normalizeBetweenArrays(x, method="vsn")
```

But after running the 3rd line I am getting this error message-

```
Error in normalizeBetweenArrays(x, method = "vsn") : 
vsn method no longer supported. Please use normalizeVSN instead.
```

Any idea what does that mean and how can I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there are no useful answers here, you might try asking on the [Bioconductor](https://support.bioconductor.org) support forum; it seems like a natural place for this topic.

Answer (score 0):

there is an independent function for that. Use the following code:

```
y <- normalizeVSN(x)
```